# Load data to Spark fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to load data to Spark for same processing as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import sqlContext.implicits._

val hiveObj = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = hiveObj.sql("select * from table.database_name")
```

I get the following error:

```
18/07/23 17:28:31 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select * from table.database_name 18/07/23 17:28:31 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: `table`.`database_name`; line 1 pos xx
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:50) 
.......................................................
```

However, when I run the following command it works fine (I can see the list of table I have displayed):

```
val df = hiveObj.sql("show tables in d_dmzud10trac01").show()
```

Why am I still getting this error?

Comment: If anything it is `database_name.table`.

Comment: So.. it works!!! thanks @user8371915